# Button does not get hidden on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I would hide a buttons except the last one . But when I put mouse over prevous elements, they get displayed.

Here's my html

```
<p-growl [(value)]="msgs"></p-growl>
<div class="center" appMcard>
    <h2> Select Group (s) name(s) </h2>
    <form [formGroup]="GroupRMPM_FG" class="form">
        <div formArrayName="GroupId_Name"   *ngFor="let control of GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls; let i= index" >
         <input  type="text" pInputText [formControl]="control.controls.Group_Id_Name"/>
            <button pButton type="button" class="delete-btn " *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteGroup(i)" icon="fa-minus" >
            </button>
            <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length == i+1" pButton type="button" (click)="addNewGroup()" icon="fa-plus"  class="add-btn formcontainer"></button>


        <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length != i+1" pButton type="button" class="dummyElement" icon="fa-plus" ></button>
        <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length == 1" pButton type="button" class="dummyElement" icon="fa-plus" ></button>

        </div>
    </form>
<div>
```

I have created a "dummy element" so that the content is centred in the right way when I get only a "plus" icon .

Here's the CSS:

```
.dummyElement, .dummyElement:hover{
    background-color:transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor:none;
    color: transparent;

}
```

Here's what I get

[image: Button shown when Hover]

Also the cursor is disappearing when I'm over the button.
In my Browser dev tool show me this :

[image: browser inspector]

For information I use primeNg Button.

Comment: could you add a working Snippet or Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `pointer-events: none;` instead of `cursor:none` as below;

```
.dummyElement, .dummyElement:hover{
background-color:transparent;
border-color: transparent;
pointer-events: none;
color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your CSS is overwritten by another CSS rule. Try to add `!important` to your CSS:

```
.dummyElement, .dummyElement:hover{
    background-color:transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor:none;
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: It's almost working ! but I have a last tiny problem , Cursor is hidden when I hover the button .

Comment: Sure because of `cursor: none;`. Remove this line an the cursor should be visible